# Wpf DataGrid Right "Gutter" IsSelected Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In a Wpf DataGrid, each row has a blank area that grows to fill the remaining space. I imagine this area is more appropriately called a "gutter", but I actually don't know the proper terminology for it. I like having this, but I noticed a problem with it. If I click on the blank area, it does not seem to process the `IsSelected` trigger that I have set on the Row. However, the `IsMouseOver` trigger is fired. Very strange. Here is a picture demonstrating the area that I have mentioned:

[image]

And here is the segment of Xaml that I think will be required to fix this. If more is needed, just tell me and I will post it.

```
<!--  Style and template for the DataGridRow.  -->
    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="2,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="Red"
                        Text="!" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="DGR_Border"
                        Background="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerContextBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                            <DataGridRowHeader
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!--
                            Alternation Coloration Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerContextBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerControlBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--
                            Is Selected Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <!--
                            Is Mouse Over Triggers
                        -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VoidwalkerBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Just to clarify my question even further:

When I click on the "Gutter" area in the picture, my `IsSelected` trigger is not fired. If I click on any cell to the left of it, that row will be selected. The strange thing is that my other `IsMouseOver` trigger is still fired when mousing over the gutter area. Is there a way that I can emulate the `IsSelected` behavior on the gutter area for the row it is on?

Answer (score 1):

It's only the actual cells that are selectable. You can easily make the "gutter" selectable by simply adding another blank column to your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Or make the last existing column stretch horizontally by setting its `Width` to `*`.